# Url for google finance unable to get data

Tags: google-finance, google-finance-api

I am using this link to get multiple quotes for my own app

`https://www.google.com/finance/info?infotype=infoquoteall&q=SGX:U11,ASX:TPM,ASX:WOW`

However, it stop working now. Any alternatives google api that can get data for multiple quotes at one time?

Answer (score 0):

well, I guess you're not in contact with Google, so heads up: it is very likely that you're violating their terms and conditions of use

> You agree not to copy, modify, reformat, download, store, reproduce, reprocess, transmit or redistribute any data or information found herein or use any such data or information in a commercial enterprise without obtaining prior written consent. All data and information is provided “as is” for personal informational purposes only, ...

https://www.google.com/googlefinance/disclaimer/